# Android - How to navigate ViewFlipper in AppWidget prior to Honeycomb

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-appwidget, remoteview

I'm writing flippable app widget and I run in the problem described below while trying to navigate the views.

The widget is simply a ViewFlipper with two buttons that when clicked should navigate through the child views of the ViewFlipper.

I just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282452/viewflipper-in-app-widgets) for API 11+ however this solution will only work in Honeycomb since prior to that `RemoteViews#showNext|showPrevious` did not exist. I tried to do `root.setInt(R.id.scroll, "setDisplayedChild", pos)` but that generated `android.widget.ViewFlipper can't use method with RemoteViews: setDisplayedChild(int)` exception.

So now I have a properly populated `ViewFlipper` in my widget and I can't flip through views. I would really appreciate help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ViewFlipper` in an app widget prior to API Level 11.

Comment: Yep, figured it out. Said that - there are widgets out there that are "scrollable" - any hints on how they do it?

Comment: @DroidIn.net: I'm not quite certain what you mean by "scrollable" in this case. For example, the older version of the Remember The Milk app widget had an effect where a to-do list item was highlighted, and up/down arrow keys/trackball/etc. would change that. I am guessing that widgets on app widgets can still be selectable and have focus, and they used a background `StateListDrawable` to achieve the effect. Since very few Android devices have pointing devices, though, I'm skeptical that it is worth much effort.

Comment: Just a dumb scenario when you have list of things and use navigation buttons to flip left or right. Right now I retain the data and then for each click I redraw title, message and background image but I'm wondering if there's a better way