# Is there any way to use ViewPager's behavior in app widget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-appwidget

I am writing an `app widget` for very first time, and came to know that there are too many restrictions on it.

I know I can't use `ViewPager` and any `custom view` inside an `app widget`, but I need to use `ViewPager`'s left-right sliding effect. Please have a look at this..

[image]

Requirement is, whenever user taps on left arrow (top left corner) next list will slide in from right, there are three lists to be displayed one by one, and this will go circularly, 
ie. -L1-L2-L3-L1-

is there any way to implement this?

Comment: A ViewPager is used for horizontal scrolling of child fragments (with swipe gesture), which is not a good idea as it'll then restrict the horizontal movement of the launcher.

Comment: that I know @Saket.. but one can disable the swipe in ViewPager by extending it and could achieve the horizontal-scroll/slide from other widget like button.. have a look at ViewPageIndicator library..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If gestures are not what you seek, then you should simply use a `ViewFlipper`. It's similar to `ViewPager` except that it does not support gestures and requires pages to be changed pragmatically.

So when your user presses the left arrow, you can simply call `viewPager.showPrev()` to go back to the previous page.

You can also add page enter / exit animations in this way:

```
viewFlipper.setInAnimation(context, R.anim.page_in_animation);
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(context, R.anim.page_out_animation);
viewFlipper.showPrev();
```

Comment: yay!! `ViewPager` is the ans.. but one need to understand the RemoteViews api to implement this.. see my answer..

Answer (score 0):

used `ViewFlipper` to implement mentioned behavior.

following is the code of extended `AppWidgetProvider`

```
public static final String TRIGGER = "trigger";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
    int[] allAppWidgetIds) {

    for (int appWidgetId : allAppWidgetIds) {
         RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
             R.layout.layout_widget);

         Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, CueWidgetProvider.class);
         clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
         clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
         clickIntent.putExtra(CueWidgetProvider.TRIGGER, 
             R.id.app_wid_fltr_next_btn);

         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
              0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app_wid_fltr_next_btn, 
            pendingIntent);

         appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Integer id = (Integer) (extras == null ? null : extras.get(TRIGGER));

    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action) 
        && id != null) {

        int widgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 0);
        onNavigate(context, widgetId, id);
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}

protected void onNavigate(Context context, Integer widgetId, Integer id) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews root = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.layout_widget);

    if (id == R.id.app_wid_fltr_next_btn) {
        root.showNext(R.id.app_wid_fltr_flipper);
    }

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, root);
}
```

referred answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282452/viewflipper-in-app-widgets) question.